# How can I add compoent to another component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I add component Country.js to component Countries.js

I want to display in browser:

Name: France

Capital: Paris

Name: Russia

Capital: Moscow

**//First component Country.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Country extends Component {
    render() {
        const {data} = this.props;
            return (
              <div className = {'countryItem'}>
                <p className = {'countryLabel'}> 
                    Name:  {{this.props.country.name}}
                </p>
                <p className= {'contactLabel'}> 
                    Capital: {{this.props.country.capital}}
                </p>
              </div>                
           )   

        return (
            <div>
                {Country}
            </div>
        )
    }
  }

export default Country;
```

**//Second component Countries.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Country from './Country';



class Countries extends Component {
    render() {
        const {data} = this.props;
        const Countries = data.map(country => {
            return (
                <li key = {country.id}>
                    <h2>{country.name}</h2>
                    <p>{country.capital}</p>
                </li>                  
            )   
        })
        return (
            <ul>
                {Countries}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

export default Countries;
```

**//Data.js**

```
export default  [       
        {
           id: 1,
           Name: 'France',
           Capital: 'Paris
        },
        {
           id: 2,
           Name: 'Russia',
           Capital: 'Moscow'
        }]
```

**//HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

**//App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CountryForm from './components/CountryForm';
import Countries from './components/Countries';



class App extends Component {
    render() {      
        return (            
            <div>
                <div><CountryForm /></div>
                <div><Countries data={this.props.data}/></div>
            </div>      
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**//script.js**

```
var app = React.createElement(App);
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I want to display in browser:

Name: France

Capital: Paris

Name: Russia

Capital: Moscow

Thank you for your help

Comment: Could it just be a typo?  You put "contact.id" instead of "country.id"

Comment: it should be 'country.id'. Do you know how can I connect  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
var data = [
    {
       id: 1,
       Name: 'France',
       Capital: 'Paris'
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       Name: 'Russia',
       Capital: 'Moscow'
    }];

class Country extends React.Component {
render() {
        return (
          <div className = 'countryItem'>
            <p className = 'countryLabel'>
                Name:  {this.props.name}
            </p>
            <p className= {'contactLabel'}>
                Capital: {this.props.capital}
            </p>
          </div>
       )
     }
}

class Countries extends React.Component {

render() {
    const style = {
      listStyleType: 'none'
    }
    const {data} = this.props;
    const countries = data.map(country => {
        return (
            <li key = {country.id}>
                <Country name={country.Name} capital={country.Capital} 
                />
            </li>
        )
    })
    return (
        <ul style={style}>
            {countries}
        </ul>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div><Countries data={data}/></div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
 <App />,
 document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
    in ul (at Countries.js:17)
    in Countries (at App.js:15)
    in div (at App.js:15)
    in div (at App.js:13)
    in App (at index.js:8)

Comment: @Mario Added script.js to above answer. Can you please try once again replacing script.js with above?

Comment: @Mario I tested before posting my answer. It worked for me.

Comment: @Mario Here is the working fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/dt5svj9o/

Answer (score 0):

It would take a bit more code reworking than I can do on the fly, but basically you would want to do something like this in Countries.js:

```
<li key = {country.id}>
    <Country country={country}>
</li>
```

Hopefully this gives you the info you need to solve the rest of it.

Comment: I added your code. Display: "name:", "capital", but doesn't display France, Paris

Answer (score 0):

In the render function of `Countries.js`, you should **spread** the countries array when return the result, like this:

```
return (
  <ul>
    { ...Countries } // you miss the spread operator
  </ul>
)
```

Also, in your example code, you are actually not reusing your `Country` component class.

You should also make it like:

```
const countries = data.map(country => (
  <li id={country.id}>
    <Country name={country.name} capital={country.capital}>
  </li>
))
```

And modify your `Country.js`. Yours is actually so messy.

> Refer to this for a clean explanation about how to compose React
>   components: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html